# Open hangout in new tab

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

I've integrated a hangout button into my website. When I click it a child window is opened. Is it possible to make hangout opened in current tab or in a new tab (like a usual link does)?

I've looked through [Hangout Button](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button) documentation but haven't found anything like this (while I believe I saw it somewhere over the Internet).

**Update** There was a couple of examples how you can specify a new hangout url without Hangout Button in the answers and comment. But no proves were provided that this is a reliable way and no documentation was provided about the ways to specify additional parameters (e. g. startDate for Hangout App).

**Update 2** I've found that when you create a new hangout app Google Develope Console provides a Hangout link:

[image]

with the following url: https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/hangouts?authuser=0&gid=appId. Does it work only for sandbox? Is there any way to specify other parameters like startData?

Comment: Looks like a simple `<a href="https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_">Start Hangout</a>` works, but it's probably totally against the Terms of Service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the following to open hangout in a new tab

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_?gid=<app_id">Start a Hangout</a>
```

Use the query parameter `gd=somevalue` to pass your app an initial set of data

```
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/running#passing-data
```

I send start data like this

```
https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_?gid=<app_id">&gd=<start_data>
```

and also like this

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div id="placeholder-rr"></div>
<script>
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-rr', {
    'render': 'createhangout',
    'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : 'Your app_id', 'start_data' : 'Put your start data here', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
    'widget_size': 175
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Two questions: 1. Is it documented anywhere? 2. How to specify startData for a custom Hangout App

Comment: @Idsa Yes there is no proof that this is a reliable way and no documentation is provided about the ways to specify additional parameters. The documentation is not good. When I developed this, I had to try out all combinations to understand. And Enter a Hangout in developer sandbox doesn't work anymore

Comment: You are right about gid and gd parameters. There are some other parameters but it seems like the only way to get them is to reverse engineer how ugly Hangout Button works. Here is, for example, the way to start a new Hangout On Air: https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_?hso=0&gid=APP_ID&gd=JSON_ENCODED_DATA

Comment: @Idsa Thanks for https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_?hso=0&gid=APP_ID&gd=JSON_ENCODED_DATA because I didn't know if we could send more paramters to gd.

Answer (score 3):

Checked the documentation, doesn't seem that the button is meant to be flexible with configuration.

---

If you're looking for a coding solution  apart than:

```
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div', {
    'render': 'createhangout',
    'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '184219133185', 'start_data' : 'dQw4w9WgXcQ', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
    'widget_size': 200
  });
```

Deferred execution and language configuration:

```
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'zh-CN',
    parsetags: 'onload'
  };
```

[not much can be done](http://jsfiddle.net/carlodurso/95mhvw3g/).

On the manual side, holding ⌘ (CTRL on windows) while clicking on the button will open the hangout in a new tab instead.

**Tested successfully on Chrome and Safari.**
*Unsuccessful on Firefox.*

Comment: I've also found nothing in the documentation. But there is a way to do that. If you go to https://www.verbling.com/community and click on "Start a group" (you have to sign in) and then create a group you will get a normal hangout anchor.

Comment: Btw, thank you for a workaroudn with Ctrl. It's at least something I can use for now.

Comment: You're welcome. The reason that site is able to produce an URL is because they are taking advantage of the [Hangout API method getHangoutUrl()](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout#gapi.hangout.getHangoutUrl). That is possible when writing an app, but not with a button widget. Hope it helps.

Comment: I also use custom Hangout App to get hangout url. But to get the url you have to launch the hangout. But in the workflow I provided above nobody launches the hangout.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plain link button available:

```
https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/hangouts/_?gid=APP_ID
```

You can simply open this link in a new tab:

```
<a href="https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/hangouts/_?gid=184219133185">Hangout</a>
```

Comment: Is there any documentation about it? How can I specify start_data and app_type?

Comment: It's an old version of documentation, there is only `gid`. You can try to pass `start_data` and `app_type` as parameters, but there is no guarantee. You probably should ask google support about it.